# Python requests print выводит ответ сервера 500

Tags: python, парсер, requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://es.ciur.ru/auth/login"
homework_url = "https://es.ciur.ru/api/HomeworkService/GetHomeworkFromRange"

header = {
     'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = header

data = {
    'login_login': 'тут был логин',
    'login_password': 'тут был пароль',
    'login_next':'/'
    }

response = session.post(url, data=data)
responce = session.get(homework_url)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
print(responce.status_code)
print(responce.text)
```

Делаю парсер домашнего задания из электронного дневника

```
print(response.status_code)
Выводит ответ 200
```

```
print(response.text)
Выводит ответ {"success": true, "redirect": "/"}
```

```
print(responce.status_code)
Выводит ответ 500
```

```
print(responce.text)

Выводит ответ {"faultcode": "Server", "faultstring": "\u0412\u044b \u043d\u0435 \u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u044b!", "detail": ""}  
То есть вы не авторизованы
```

Сайт динамический ссылка взята из подгружаемого запроса с домашним заданием

Comment: я же использую сессию

Comment: А, увидел. Ну тогда идей нет.